# Change color of maxletters in textfiled flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

[image]

How to change color of this? and position other place.( like center of top )

Code:

```
TextField(
      maxLength: 25,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      obscureText: obscuretext,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        border: InputBorder.none,
        iconColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
        hintText: hintText,
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          fontSize: 16,
          color: Colors.grey.shade800,
        ),
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Colors.white54,
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code and use [**`buildCounter`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/buildCounter.html)

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
  child: TextFormField(
    maxLength: 25,
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
       // If you want change color only of counterText then refer below style
      /*counterStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.green,
      ),*/
    ),
    buildCounter: (BuildContext context,
            {int? currentLength, int? maxLength, bool? isFocused}) =>
        Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,//use alignment position on your need
      child: Text(
        '${currentLength.toString()}/${maxLength.toString()}',
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.indigo,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Answer (score 1):

you can build your custom counter

```
TextField(
  maxLength: 25,
  buildCounter: (_, {currentLength, maxLength, isFocused}) => Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(currentLength.toString() + "/" + maxLength.toString()),
  ),
)
```